# where clause equality understanding

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have difficulty understanding this `WHERE` clause including equality condition in terms of algorithmic process. 
 (I suppose I can't get the SQL grammar below since I can't really picture the process in which `WHERE carrier= f.carrier` clause is run step-by-step like in algorithm. (like I see the result set table and how it's processed in order))

```
SELECT id 
FROM flights AS f
WHERE distance < ( SELECT AVG(distance) 
                   FROM flights
                   WHERE carrier = f.carrier);
```

So, as I understand it, the process of running `carrier=f.carrier` goes like:

1. Since it's a correlated subquery, the computer starts from outer subquery, meaning it takes just first row in a flight table and then goes on to inner subquery.
2. In a inner subquery, it tries to find the same carrier of outer subquery's first row data and find the average of that specific carrier's distance. And it compares the average with the outer subquery's first row record and return the outcome. It does this until it finishes the whole table.

Is my understanding of sequence process correct? Thank you so much for reading!

Comment: Your explanation looks correct to me.  Do you have another question?

Comment: Your explanation is correct. It may be helpful for you to run an `EXPLAIN PLAN` or review the query plan (depending on your RDBMS, the nomenclature, exact syntax and output will vary) to see how the database interprets and processes the query.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is eternally useful. Just prefix your query with `EXPLAIN` and you can see the query plan which will show you how each table is searched and which indexes are used. It's very handy.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen - thank you so much for your explanation! I just really wanted to know the discrete process order behind it even if it's more of educational concept. Have a nice day!

Comment: alroc - thank you! I didn't know explain keyword:)

Comment: matt - than you! I have tried in codecademy but it didn't show any results. maybe I need to try it in python?

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is correct.  Just for educational purposes, here is how you could do the same query using a join:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM flights t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT carrier, AVG(distanct) AS average_distance
    FROM flights
    GROUP BY carrier
) t2
    ON t1.carrier = t2.carrier
WHERE t1.distance < t2.average_distance
```

The non-correlated subquery finds the average distance for each `carrier`, and these values are then joined back to the original `flights` table.  The `WHERE` clause compares the distance values from `flights` against the average values for the same carrier to decide which records to retain in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is correct.  However, if you are writing queries with more than one table, you should get in the habit of qualifying *all* column names.  This is especially important with correlated subqueries, where mistakes can be very subtle:

```
SELECT f.id 
FROM flights f
WHERE f.distance < (SELECT AVG(f2.distance) 
                    FROM flights f2
                    WHERE f2.carrier = f.carrier
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is correct. That's basically what it's going to do, at least conceptually. If there's one thing that databases are good at, it's optimizations. That means that it may not actually work the way you think it might, even if you get the results you expect.

The best way to see what it's actually doing is to look at the query plan, which are the actual steps taken by the database to run the query. Most databases provide tools for viewing these. This is often a good idea when your query is not running as fast as you think it should.